# I can't install theano after reinstalling anaconda

Tags: git, installation, theano

I get this with this command line after reinstalling anaconda. Why is that?

```
pip install --upgrade --no-deps git+git://github.com/Theano/Theano.git

(C:\Users\AM\Anaconda3) C:\Users\AM\Documents>pip install --upgrade --no-
deps git+git://github.com/Theano/Theano.git 
Collecting git+git://github.com/Theano/Theano.git
  Cloning git://github.com/Theano/Theano.git to c:\users\am\appdata\local\temp\p
ip-273x97zk-build
  Error [WinError 2] The system cannot find the file specified while 
executing command git clone -q git://github.com/Theano/Theano.git C:\Users\AM\AppData\Local
\Temp\pip-273x97zk-build
Cannot find command 'git'
```

Also, what's the difference between

```
pip install --upgrade --no-deps git+git://github.com/Theano/Theano.git
```

&

```
pip install git+git://github.com/Theano/Theano.git
```

I don't know which one to use, so confusing.

I am running python 3.6, do I have to downgrade to 3.5?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error in the output is:

```
Cannot find command 'git'
```

Install git (I think there's a git powershell for windows), and try to run the command after

Comment: It works. Thanks! What is this git thing by the way? I don't think I installed it before, but it worked somehow. So weird...